# Why does the Python socket implementation send TCP segment with URG-flag?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, flags

I'm using python 2.7 socket to establish a TCP connection to a server, send segments (diameter requests such as CCR) and receive answers (e.g. CCA).

When I refactored the code a bit in order to send some request data based on the previous answer, I noticed - by checking TCP dump - that my third request (3rd socket.send(..)) is sent with an URG flag on the TCP layer which seems to cause the receiving application to fail and close the connection.

The previous version of the code happily works for multiple send/recv (CCR/CCA) pairs.
I don't manage to figure out what change in the code could possibly cause the socket implementation to send the URG flag.

## Working

main.py

```py
sd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sd.settimeout(5)
try:
    sd.connect((someHost, somePort))
except ...
... # Create stream for CER
sd.send(cer)
try:
    connection.recv(1024)
except ...

ccrCreator = creator.CCRCreator(...) # A class that knows to create the stream
manager = mpc.Manager()
queue = manager.Queue()
ccrCreator.subscribe(queue)
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target = ccrCreator.start)
... # The ccrCreator's start method creates the CCR stream to be sent and puts
... # it on the queue
proc.start()
...
while True:
    stream = queue.get()
    if stream == None:
        break
    else:
        sd.send(stream)
        try:
            result = sd.recv(2048)
        except ...
... # Working fine, no URG flag sent at any moment
```

## Not working

main.py

```py
sd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sd.settimeout(5)
try:
    sd.connect((someHost, somePort))
except ...
... # Create stream for CER
sd.send(cer) # Send without URG flag
try:
    sd.recv(1024)
except ...

ccrCreator = creator.CCRCreator(sd, ...) # A class that knows to create the stream
ccrCreator.createCCRs()
```

creator.py

```py
class CCRCreator(object)
    def __init__(self, sd)
        self.sd = sd

    def createCCRs(self)
        for line in confFile.readlines
             .... # get some info from conf into ccrInfo
             self.sendRecvOneCCR(ccrInfo)

    def sendRecvOneCCR(self, ccrInfo)
        ... # Create stream from ccrInfo
        self.sd.sendall(stream)
        # Works fine first time - no URG flag sent
        # Second time, URG flag is sent and receiver closes socket
        # Why??
        try:
            result = self.sd.recv(2048) # Result as expected first time
            ... # parse result and put some info from it on self
            ... # to be used in the next stream (CCR)
        except ...

        return
```

Comment: This must be a bug in Python.

Comment: There is no way to reproduce the problem based on these code snippets only. My guess is that it is not a problem in Python but a problem in your code - only in a part which you don't show or which you show but do not replicate correctly in the snippets. Please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for others to reproduce the issue. Note that URG gets used if you do a `send(data,1)` or similar with `sendall`.